# error when connecting my android app to my local sql server

Tags: android, sql-server, jdbc, android-studio

I am getting error when connecting my android app to my local sql server (same pc via visual studio)

> 27506-27506/com.example.jacquesarroyo.onlinelibrary E/ERROR﹕ Network
>   error IOException: failed to connect to /10.0.0.5 (port 1433): connect
>   failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Here's my code:

```
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
errorlbl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblerror);
title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txttitle);
author = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtauthor);
year = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtyear);
location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtlocation);

ipaddress = "10.0.0.5";   
db = "SampleDatabase"; 
username = "admin"
 password = "admin";
connect = ConnectionHelper(username, password, db, ipaddress);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                st = connect.createStatement();
                preparedStatement = connect
                        .prepareStatement("Insert into Books(Title,Author,Year) values ('"
                                + title.getText().toString()
                                + "','"
                                + author.getText().toString()
                                + "','"
                                + year.getText().toString() + "')");
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                errorlbl.setText("Data Added successfully");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                errorlbl.setText(e.getMessage().toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

the IP address I used is my lan ip address.

Comment: ... and on your phone you are on the same network as your Desktop?

Comment: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) very often means "Windows firewall".  Do the following: 1) Follow the steps in this link to enable SQL server to communicate via TCP/IP (this is *not* enabled by default): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee248622%28v=VS.90%29.aspx,2) Make sure you can connect with sqlcmd, 3) Make sure Windows Firewall permits MSSQL on your PC

Comment: @paulsm4 I wonder why my configuration manager is empty

Comment: SQL-INJECTION, bind parameters, don't concatenate.

Comment: Can you show us your **ConnectionHelper**?